# Deploying java applications to Tomcat using CruiseControl.net

Tags: java, tomcat, cruisecontrol, war

I have CruiseControl.net setup on a machine which is currenly being used for Microsoft Projects. 
I needed to add a java project to the same build server.
The java war files generated need to be copied to another server under Tomcat. 
However, I face a lot of problems when it tries to copy to that network location, due to file access denied messages, as certain jar files are being used.

I tried to remotely stop tomcat before attempting to copy the files but wasnt successful doing that.

Answer (score 0):

There are [Ant tasks](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/manager-howto.html) that allow you to admin Tomcat using build.xml.  Maybe those can help.